# Corn VS Sweetcorn in American English

Tags: vocabulary

In american english, when you say the word 'corn', are you referring to the maze plant or the sweetcorn or the maze plant's seeds?

Comment: Either way it's *maize* with an *i*.

Comment: What is 'sweetcorn'? In AmE there's a variety of the corn plant called 'sweet corn' which is corn (what in BrE is called maize) that is for humans to eat (the other kinds are for livestock).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/corn)

> **corn**<sup>1</sup>
>   *n.*
>   1.
>   a. Any of numerous cultivated forms of a widely grown, usually tall annual cereal grass (*Zea mays*) bearing grains or kernels on large ears.
>   b. The grains or kernels of this plant, used as food for humans and livestock or for the extraction of an edible oil or starch. Also called *Indian corn, maize*.
>   2. An ear of this plant.

and

> **sweetcorn**
>   *n.*
>   1. (Plants) Also called: **sugar corn** or **green corn**. A variety of maize, *Zea mays saccharata*, whose kernels are rich in sugar and eaten as a vegetable when young

So the answer is *yes* to all three questions.

Comment: You probably know, but others may not that all this is completely different in Britain. "Corn" is a generic term covering all kinds of cereal crops. We say "corn" where Americans say "grain". Maize is popularly known as "sweetcorn".

Comment: _Maize_ is not a word that's used much for corn in the U.S. It's probly more common as a color name. _Corn_ and _grain_ are from the same PIE root, but one's been through the Grimm's Law Mill and the other hasn't. Where I come from (DeKalb County, IL; corn country), there's field corn -- basically, dent corn: animal fodder and industrial feedstock, dried hard kernels -- and then there's sweet corn, which humans eat. Popcorn is another variety, and so is flint ("Indian" multicolored) corn. _Corn_ refers to the plant, the crop, the ear, the kernel, and everything else. But only of _Zea mays_.